# How to delete a file named `aux`

Tags: windows, filenames, rm

I have a file named `aux` in a directory

```
...> ls
aux

...> dir
 Wolumin w stacji C nie ma etykiety.
 Numer seryjny woluminu: ...

 Katalog: C:\Users\...\config

2015-07-15  23:14    <DIR>          .
2015-07-15  23:14    <DIR>          ..
2007-12-01  04:49               511 aux
               1 plik(ów)                511 bajtów
               2 katalog(ów)  76 382 707 712 bajtów wolnych
```

and when I'm trying to remove it (`rm`), I get the following error:

```
rm: aux: No such file or directory
```

`del` also doesn't work:

```
Nazwa pliku, nazwa katalogu lub składnia etykiety woluminu jest niepoprawna.
```

*(File name, directory name or volume label syntax is invalid.)*

How do I remove this file?

Comment: Have you tried `cd ..` followed by `rd config`?

Comment: @DavidPostill It says that the directory is not empty

Comment: OK. Go back into `config` and try `del "\\?\%CD%\aux"`

Comment: Wow, `del "\\?\%CD%\aux"` worked. Please add this as an answer :)

Comment: I would but I stole it from the duplicate ;) You should be able to accept (agree) the duplicate request?